# .Cells VBA reference issue

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

I have this VBA below that is designed to loop through each WS and insert the top 4 rows of each data set.

This works fine inside of a with, but that only lets me specify one sheet, instead of going through them all. I took the with out and got "Invalid or unqualified reference". After this I added ActiveSheet. to the 'Cells' Method.

Now I'm getting this error below:

"ODBC driver doesn't support the requested properties"

How do I qualify .Cells now? Or is there an alternative? I'm using excel 2010 and mysql.

```
Public Function InsertData()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim strsql As String

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=server.host.com;" & _
    "DATABASE=datatime;" & _
    "USER=boulders;" & _
    "PASSWORD=rocks;" & _
    "Option=3"


For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For rowcursor = 4 To 8
        strsql = "INSERT INTO workflow_metrics (id, code) " & _
            "VALUES (" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(rowcursor, 1)) & "," & _
            "'" & (ActiveSheet.Cells(rowcursor, 2)) & "')"

       rs.Open strsql, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    Next
Next WS


End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Param1.Value = WS.Cells(rowcursor, 1)
```

etc.

Comment: +1 You're right about `WS` instead of ActiveSheet.Cells but would that cause `ODBC driver doesn't support the requested properties`

Comment: Awesome, swapped out ActiveSheet. for WS. and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

> How do I qualify .Cells now? Or is there an alternative?

This isn't the problem. The problem is you trying to open a recordset (`rs.open`) using a Data Modification Query (`INSERT`).

For DML you want to use [ADODB.Command.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also if you don't have control of the values in the Spreadsheet you're opening yourself up to a SQL Injection Attack. You should use a parameterized query instead.

```
 Dim Cmd As ADODB.Command
 Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command
 Cmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
 Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO workflow_metrics (id, code) VALUES (?,?)"

 Set Param1 = Cmd.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, 5)
 Set Param2 = Cmd.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, 5)


 For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


     For rowcursor = 4 To 8
         Param1.Value = WS.Cells(rowcursor, 1) 'As Doug Glancy this should be WS not ActiveSheet'
         Param2.Value = WS.Cells(rowcursor, 2)
         cmd1.Execute
     Next
 Next  WS
```

Comment: Hmmm, well it works great inside of a with statement, we've been using this model on a few things for a while. The datatypes are restricted in mysql if that's what you meant by controlling values.

Based on what I've gathered from Microsoft, .Cells doesn't work by itself outside of a with statement. What is the best way I can use to reference it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What I meant by controlling the spreadsheet values is that you can ensure that a cell won't contain `); Drop Table workflow metrics; --`

Comment: I see what you mean.

I'm a little confused by the "INSERT INTO workflow_metrics (id, code) VALUES (?,?)" you have. Were you suggesting to have manual values in there? This data comes in from webqueries and will change each day. How do do the VALUES link to the commands below?

Comment: the question marks act as place holders. The db will use Param1.value and param2.value when the command gets executed. Do a search for sql injection and paramerterized queries for a good explanation